# Is it possible to have an RX observable that repeats forever

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I'd like to create a heartbeat via RX, and I can't seem to find a way to create an `Observable` which will pulse indefinitely.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var forever = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
```

Comment: No worries. I think that the `Timer` extension throws people when it only produces a single value.